# I added a folder to my main_pages folder and put a page in the new folder now my include is not working

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

[image: The error that is being thrown by the code all my other pages are fine][image of file layout that is causing error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vE)

[image: w]zd.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Relative path to the partials has changed after you have put the  `pomly.js` under the writings folder.

Either put it under main_pages or change the path to the `navbar` from `../partials/navabar` to `../../partials/navabar`

Assuming the folder structure is

```
 - main_pages
   - writing
     pomly.js
   - partials
     navabar
```

Comment: Hey @Ulysses Hill, let me know if this does not solve your issue. If it does, pls accept the answer

Comment: The partials are in a seperate folder from main pages.